# jquery validation additional method not to accept empty string, for name field dont accept empty space before string

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I would like to add a validation in additional method of jQuery validation for the name field so that
don't accept full space as name, ie can not be empty space
first should be characters no space in front of that name like-(space space name(  name) should not be accepted)
name should not accept special characters or numbers
should accept space in between like (test name)
Please help me to solve this.
Thank you in advance
i have used the below code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element)   { 
    //Code used for blank space Validation 
    return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
    }, "No space please and don't leave it empty"); 

 fname: {
          required: true,
          noSpace: true    
        },
```

This will not accept space in between name.

Comment: Questions need code examples  - also what research you've done and what you've tried. You need to share in the solution